# partial sums of euler function through divisors

Tags: analytic-number-theory, totient-function

Does anybody know how to find a nice upper bound for a sum of the type

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k\mid n\atop{ k\le x}}\varphi(k)$$ when $n$ is fixed?

I found that this sum is close to $x$ when $n$ is a power of a prime.

Note: $\varphi(\cdot)$ is the Totient Euler Function. Thks.

Comment: If $n$ is fixed, then this sum is equal to $\sum_{k \mid n} \varphi(k) = n$ for all $x \geq n$.